# Sci-Fi short animation - Heist, robot unlocks door by kissing it

Tags: story-identification, animation, short-film

I watched an animated short-film (under 10 minutes) on YouTube about some sort of heist.  I think it was either someone's personal project, or maybe an animation school project.  It's in a Sci-Fi setting, maybe on a space station, or at least in some sort of building a ship could dock in.

It starts out in the lower levels in a restaurant or a fancy dinner party.  The robot is short enough to go under tables, maybe can even fold down to be roomba sized, and it has a digital screen that displays its face.  The robot is maybe acting like it is a server at the dinner at first.  It meets up with the thief.

The thief and the robot partner sneak off into the halls.  And here is the most memorable part: the robot goes over to this door/elevator, and to get past the security, it stands up to the security terminal and ***kisses*** it (and the terminal kisses back) and then the door opens.

In the end, the thief gets to a computer and transfers a bunch of credits off of an account.  I think that they make a getaway in a small ship, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you but generally this has a big Lexx felling to it, but that's a live-action movie/tv series. Also, the book QualityLand by  Marc-Uwe Kling features biometric kiss-locks, so maybe someone made a fan-animation inspired by this book.